# Error: SQLite parces a command as an error

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I have encountered an error while using SQLite in Python that I do not understand.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/piotr/Desktop/LDCS-dark-data-qualitative-analysis/run_add_cleaning.py", line 25, in <module>
    add_duplicate_number.add_duplicate_number(database)
  File "/home/piotr/Desktop/LDCS-dark-data-qualitative-analysis/add_duplicate_number.py", line 139, in add_duplicate_number
    con.execute("ALTER TABLE {} ADD duplicate INTEGER;".format(row))
KeyError: ('SELECT FileCreationTime,id FROM v124GeV1eecalphotonuclear WHERE file_number LIKE ?;',)
```

For some reason, the "Key Error" is referencing another SQLite command earlier in the script

`creation_time = con.execute("SELECT FileCreationTime,{} FROM {} WHERE file_number LIKE ?;".format(column,row), (int(number2),)).fetchall()`

as the error for a later command

`con.execute("ALTER TABLE {} ADD duplicate INTEGER;".format(row))`

and I have no idea what that means. I tried to google it, but nothing popped up. See full script bellow:

```
from logging import raiseExceptions
from multiprocessing.connection import wait
from tokenize import Number
from matplotlib.axis import YAxis
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sqlite3 as sl
from tqdm import *
import os
from zlib import adler32
import time
from datetime import datetime
from tqdm import *
import sqlite3 as sl
import threading
import itertools 
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


from sqlalchemy import column
def add_duplicate_number(dataset):
    



    con = sl.connect(dataset, check_same_thread=False)
    for row2 in con.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table" ORDER BY name').fetchall():
        time.sleep(0.3)
        row=row2[0]
        if row == 'sqlite_sequence':
            pass
        else:
            print("          "+row)
            try:
                con.execute("Select duplicate from %s" % row).fetchall()
            except:
                any_duplicates=con.execute("Select file_number from %s" % row).fetchall()
                
                position=list(set(any_duplicates))
                position=[a[0] for a in position]
                if len(any_duplicates)==len(list(set(any_duplicates))):
                    print("          "+"No duplicates\n\n")
                    with con:
                        con.execute("""
                        ALTER TABLE {}
                            ADD duplicate INTEGER;""".format(row))
                    con.execute("""
                    UPDATE {}
                        SET duplicate = NULL;""".format(row))
                else:
                    

                    print("          "+"Duplicates")

                    
                    

                    time_1={}
                    
                    
                        
                    def get_data(number2,row):
                        column="id"
                        
                        try:
                            creation_time = con.execute("SELECT FileCreationTime,{} FROM {} WHERE file_number LIKE ?;".format(column,row), (int(number2),)).fetchall()
                        except:
                            print(column,row,int(number2))
                            raise Exception("Error" + column + row + str(number2))
                        if len(creation_time)==0:
                            pass
                        else:
                            time=[]
                            number=[]
                            if len(creation_time)>1:
                                for i in range(len(creation_time)):
                                    time.append(creation_time[i][0])
                                    number.append(creation_time[i][1])
                                Z=[x for _, x in sorted(zip(time, number))]

                                time_1[str(number2)]=Z

                                
                            else:
                                pass
                    files=position[:50]
                    files_1=files[:len(files)//3]
                    files_2=files[len(files)//3:len(files)*2//3]
                    files_3=files[len(files)*2//3:]


                    
                    with tqdm(total=max(len(files_1),len(files_2),len(files_3))) as pbar:
                        data=[]
                        for (a1,a2,a3) in itertools.zip_longest(files_1,files_2,files_3):

                            if not a1==None:
                                t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(a1,row,))
                            if not a2==None:
                                t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(a2,row,))
                            if not a3==None:
                                t3 = threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(a3,row,))



                            if not a1==None:
                                t1.start()
                            if not a2==None:
                                t2.start()
                            if not a3==None:
                                t3.start()






  
                            if not a1==None:

                                t1.join()
                            if not a2==None:

                                t2.join()
                            if not a3==None:

                                t3.join()



                            pbar.update(1)
        
                    time_1_list=time_1
                    print(row)
                    con.execute("ALTER TABLE {} ADD duplicate INTEGER;".format(row))
                    print("          "+"Update database")

                    
                    with con:
                        for i in tqdm(time_1_list):
                            lists=time_1_list[i]
                            for n in lists:
                                con.execute("UPDATE {} SET duplicate = {} WHERE id LIKE {};".format(row,i,n))


                    print("          "+"\n\n")
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Piotr

Comment: Executing new statements while you are looping over the resultset of a previous statement is going to cause problems.  Do `row2s = con.execute(...).fetchall()` and then `for row2 in row2s:`

Comment: Did not help, still the same error after I changed to```con = sl.connect(dataset, check_same_thread=False)
    row2s=con.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table" ORDER BY name').fetchall()
    
    for row2 in row2s:```

Comment: But the problem is probably something like that, which would explain why the batch name in the key error, like v230batch11, belongs to the previous loop

Comment: I remover multithreading and it seems to work now. Shame I have to wait 3 times as long for the programme to run, but better than nothing. Thank you anyway